# Delphi/pascal destructor and c#

Tags: c#, delphi, pascal

Assume this class definition is working

```
TStringListNF = class (TStringList)
  procedure TestContenu (verif : Boolean);
  destructor DestroyList;
  destructor DestroyListFree;
end;
```

And the class body of this class is working too

```
destructor TStringListNF.DestroyList;
{//Verified 27 june 98}
var
  i : Integer;
  tempItem : TObject;
begin
  for i:= 0 to Count-1 do
    begin
      tempItem := Objects[i];
      tempItem.destroy;
    end;
  inherited destroy;
end;

destructor TStringListNF.DestroyListFree;
{//Verified 27 june 98}
var
  i : Integer;
  tempItem : TObject;
begin
  for i:=0 to Count-1 do
    begin
      tempItem := Objects[i];
      if tempItem <> nil then
        tempItem.destroy;
    end;
  inherited destroy;
end;
```

My question is why is there two destructor and how I can replicate two destructor in c#

As you can see the code is old but is working and I,m trying to get it up working on c# so what I would have to do is only to create a destructor and do whatever I want in the destructor ?

Comment: Impossible to answer. What do the destructors do. Show code. Almost certainly this code is designed very badly. You can only have one destructor in C# and you should only have one in Delphi. This class has three which is two more than it should have. Whoever designed it got it wrong.

Comment: I've added the code of the destructor part

Comment: This is the first time I've *ever* seen more than one destructor in a class. If even *you* don't know why there are two destructors there, why should anyone *assume* it's working?

Comment: This is a stringlist that frees the object associated with each string. DestroyList will raise an exception if any of the objects are nil. DestroyListFree will work will nil objects. I would implement this by descending from TStringList, overriding destroy to free each object (using Free rather than destroy).

Comment: @KeithMiller `StringList.OwnsObjects := True` seems more appropriate

Comment: @David - I wasn't aware of that. I don't think it was in Delphi 6

Comment: @KeithMiller No, I don't think it was.

Comment: @David - Nor is it in D2007

Comment: @KeithMiller even in Delphi 5 using JCL or using 10 minutes to write an ancestor

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The class has three destructors. The inherited virtual destructor, and the two declared here. However, I have never seen a situation where the correct design is to declare a new destructor. You should always override the virtual destructor declared in `TObject`.

There is simply no need for either of these destructors and they should be deleted. If the user of a string list wishes for the list to take ownership of the objects held in the list, then the `OwnsObjects` property should be set to `True`.

And even if the base class did not already support this particular functionality, the right solution is always to override the virtual destructor. If you need to vary behaviour of that destructor, then that needs to be effected using state or some other mechanism. But never by implementing new destructors.

The reason for all this is that all Delphi developers expect to be able to call `Free` on an instance and be confident that the object has been successfully destroyed. Since `Free` calls the virtual destructor declared in `TObject`, the conclusion is that all destruction code should reside in overrides of that method.

> How I can replicate two destructor in C#?

You cannot. A C# class can have only one destructor. What's more, you don't write C# destructors in the same way as you do in Delphi. C# is a garbage collected language. And Delphi does not have garbage collection.

My more general advice to you is that you should not be attempting to translate literally from Delphi to C#. You should write code that fits the language. The way classes are implemented in Delphi is similar, yet different, from C#. Write code to suit the target language.

Comment: If this code was really verified in June of 1998, then `TStringList` had no `OwnsObjects` property yet. Delphi 4 had only been available for 11 days, so there wasn't even a `TObjectList`.

Comment: @RobKennedy I love the idea that code can be verified and then the act of adding a comment is enough to prove that it works. Anyway, I added a couple of paragraphs to explain what to do if the base class doesn't happen to have the necessary functionality.